# Why Sending multiple print by javascript is blocked with firefox and how to disable it?

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm sending three print statements.

```
PagePrint=window.open('xx');
PagePrint.print();
PagePrint.print();
PagePrint.print();
```

the first print is done successfully but in the second statement `firefox` blocks printing and show this message:`(prevent this page from creating additional dialogs)`.
How to disable this dialog using `firefox configuraton` or any other ways?

Comment: Just in case the user accidentally presses "Cancel" the first two times?

Answer (score 2):

Try doing the following:

1. In the firefox URL bar, enter "about:config". A warning will pop up, but just click to continue.
2. Right click anywhere on the page and select "New -> Integer" in the popup menu.
3. Enter "dom.successive_dialog_time_limit" in the dialog box that appears, and give it the value 0.
4. Press OK to save the value.

Hopefully should let you do multiple dialog boxes.